# Delete images when uninstalling plugin

Tags: wordpress, media, uninstallation

I am developing a plugin, that allows image uploads to the media library. Its working fine, but I am having problems with the uninstall.php. Deleting the path in the database is working, but I would even like to delete the image from the media library. Is there a function to do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: where are you storing the images? are you attaching them to posts?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. They are stored in the folder uploads/img/[year]/[month]. They are not attached to a post. I used them for favicons.

Comment: In the case, store your images in a custom folder and then just delete the folder after plugin is deleted

Answer (score -1):

Since you said that **deleting the path in the database is working** I assume that you have references to all uploaded images.

So, what you can do is to delete the file first, and then delete the database record for that file afterwards.

You can delete a file using PHP `unlink()` method.

```
$file = 'PATH_TO_THE_IMAGE';
if(file_exits($file)){ //Check if file exists
     if (unlink($file)){ //Try to delete
         DELETE_RECORD_FROM_DATABASE; //On success, also delete from the database
     }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that the filename changes. Wordpress stores the files in subfolders from the uploads folder named by year and month of the upload and by the name of the uploaded file. The path for the image would be for example: "/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/favicon-1.ico". 

In the database i can delete the entries by the key, for example: delete_option( 'te_favicon' );

Comment: How do you upload the file? You can upload the file to a custom folder, then just remove the folder when the plugin uninstalled.